# Formatting Date labels using Seaborn FacetGrid

Tags: pandas, seaborn

I want to make a facet grid with variable names as the columns, and departments as the rows, and each small chart is a scatter chart of y=value and x=date

My data is sort of like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import random

datelist = pd.date_range(start="march 1 2020", end="may 20 2020", freq="w").tolist()
varlist = ["x", "y", "z", "x", "y", "z", "x", "y", "z", "x", "y", "z"]
deptlist = ["a", "a", "b", "a", "a", "b", "a", "a", "b", "a", "a", "b"]
vallist =  random.sample(range(10, 30), 12)
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': datelist, 'value': vallist, 'variable': varlist, 'department': deptlist})
```

I want to make a facet grid with variable names as the columns, and departments as the rows, and each small chart is a scatter chart of y=value and x=date

Here is what I have so far. It almost works, except I want to see dates along the bottom that are not squished together, so I would like to see "3/1    4/1     5/1" instead of full dates. But I can't figure out how to format it.

```
plt.style.use('seaborn-darkgrid')
xformatter = mdates.DateFormatter("%m-%d")
g = sns.FacetGrid(df2, row="department", col="variable", sharey='row')
g = g.map(plt.plot, "date", "value", marker='o', markersize=0.7)
datelist = pd.date_range(start="march 1 2020", end="june 1 2020", freq="MS").tolist()
g.set(xticks=datelist)
```

[image]

This is pretty close, but notice the dates along the bottom x axes. They are all scrunched together. That's why I tried to use a special date formatter but couldn't get it to work. Really what I would like is that each date shows up as mon-dd and that I can control how many tick marks appear there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the Axes object of the FacetGrid as `g.axes` (a 2D array). You could iterate over this array and change the properties of all the axes, but in your case you have `sharex=True` (the default), that means that changing the xaxis of one of the subplots will change all of the subplots at the same time.

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="department", col="variable", sharey='row')
g = g.map(plt.plot, "date", "value", marker='o', markersize=0.7)

xformatter = mdates.DateFormatter("%m/%d")
g.axes[0,0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(xformatter)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Genius :)

Comment: By the way, I get this message which I'vebeen ignoring but what does it mean? "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/converter.py:103: FutureWarning: Using an implicitly registered datetime converter for a matplotlib plotting method. The converter was registered by pandas on import. Future versions of pandas will require you to explicitly register matplotlib converters.

To register the converters:
 >>> from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
 >>> register_matplotlib_converters()
  warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning)"